# Logstash Elastic output stops loading and counts as deletes

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a strange problem. I have 5 logstash jobs to load into elastic search from DB2 using JDBC. The document ID is a number stored as string and I have strings starting with 0 and 1 on the first logstash job, strings starting with 2 and 3 on the 2nd logstash job, strings starting with 4 and 5 on the 3rd logstash job etc. Each logstash job is supposed to bring around 30M records. Each record size is ~2k. But each of the logstash job loads 24M records without any errors. After that the logstash job doesnt show any errors but _stats on elastic search shows increasing deleted count. As I look thru the logstash jobs I see that the specific document ID does not exist in elastic but its not getting loaded and is counting towards deletes.

When I run the same record on a totally new logstash instance the record gets inserted into elastic.

I am suspecting there is a limit of 50GB somewhere which is blocking these inserts into elastic from a single logstash instance. I am very confused. Can someone help.

The elastic search instance is running on a cloud environment and I dont have a dedicated cluster. I just have an index with around 12 shards of 30GB each allocated.

```
input {
    jdbc {
    #input configurations
    jdbc_driver_library => "db2jcc4-10.5.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:db2://..."
    columns_charset => {}
    jdbc_fetch_size => 2000
    jdbc_page_size => 5000000
    jdbc_paging_enabled => false
    lowercase_column_names => true
    jdbc_user => "*****"
    jdbc_password => "*****"
    statement_filepath => "part_a.sql"
    use_column_value => true
    schedule => "*/5 * * * *"
    sql_log_level => warn
    tracking_column => "lst_updt_ts"
    tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
    record_last_run => true
    last_run_metadata_path => "last_run_a.conf"
 }
}

filter {
  mutate {
  convert => {
    ...
  }
  rename => {
      ...
  }
 }
}

output {
elasticsearch {
    #output configurations
    hosts => "https://...:8443"
    index => "demographics"
            document_type => "demographics_doc"
    document_id => "%{record_id}"
    manage_template => false 
    action => "update" 
    doc_as_upsert => true 
    failure_type_logging_whitelist => [] 
    user => "..."
    password => "..."
 }
stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
 }
}
```